# Need to interpret a system of first order linear differential equations as an application to Linear Algebra.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that the Wronskian determines whether solutions are linearly independent.  But suppose I have a system like $Ax = x'$, where $x$ is a vector valued function of $t$.

Suppose $n$ is the rank of $A$, and I have $n$ linearly independent solutions to this system.  Why is it the case that the general solution is a linear combination of those solutions.

What am I missing?

Comment: A short answer: Because the set of all solutions to $x'=Ax$ is a vector space of dimension $n$.

Comment: How can I show this?

Comment: By providing a basis.

Comment: It's frustrating that your responses seem like they're from some artificial intelligence system.  Let me rephrase my question: I get that $0$ is always a solution to this system, and that any linear combination of solutions is a solution. I may even be able to come up with a set of n linearly independent functions.  But how do I show that we stop there.  Please provide something more substantive than the lazy answers you've been providing.

Comment: See, my lazy answers already showed that you solved a significant part of the problem. Let me sum up: 1) you can show that the set $S$ of solutions is a vector space; 2) you can find $n$ linearly independent solutiond. The last point is to make sure that these $n$ solutions span $S$. Any thoughts how you can do this?